# Column exists but still get this error ORA-00904: invalid identifier

Tags: oracle11g, ora-00904

Anyone can help me with this issue

```
declare 

    lv2_sql VARCHAR2(32767);

    cursor c_scv is
    select financial_code, object_id, daytime from stream_category_version;

begin

for r_scv in c_scv LOOP

  IF r_scv.financial_code = 'PURCHASE' THEN

   lv2_sql := 'UPDATE stream_category_version ' || CHR(10) || 
   'set REVN_PURCHASES_IND = ''Y'', last_updated_by = nvl(last_updated_by, created_by) '  || CHR(10) || 
   'WHERE object_id = r_scv.object_id AND daytime = r_scv.daytime';
   ecdp_dynsql.execute_statement(lv2_sql);   

  ELSIF r_scv.financial_code = 'SALE' THEN

   lv2_sql := 'UPDATE stream_category_version ' || CHR(10) || 
   'set REVN_SALES_IND = ''Y'', last_updated_by = nvl(last_updated_by, created_by) '  || CHR(10) || 
   'WHERE object_id = r_scv.object_id AND daytime = r_scv.daytime';
   ecdp_dynsql.execute_statement(lv2_sql);  


  END IF;

END LOOP; 

end;
```

I have code as shown above, but i got error saying 'ORA-00904: R_SCV.DAYTIME: invalid identifier'. I have checked the table definition for 'stream_category_version' and found the column DAYTIME as shown below

```
SQL> desc stream_category_version
Name               Type           Nullable Default Comments 
------------------ -------------- -------- ------- -------- 
OBJECT_ID          VARCHAR2(32)                             
DAYTIME            DATE                                     
END_DATE           DATE           Y                         
NAME               VARCHAR2(240)  Y                          
FINANCIAL_CODE     VARCHAR2(32)   Y                         
SORT_ORDER         NUMBER         Y                         
COMMENTS           VARCHAR2(2000) Y
```

Then i am confused with the error. Anyone can help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Shortly speaking - Oracle is case sensitive...

... probably during table creation column was typed UPPERCASE in quotation marks like that:

```
"DAYTIME"
```

and in your sql i see this column in lowercase

so you should verify your column name and best change it to version without quotation marks.

Other option is to call this column like that:

```
= r_scv.DAYTIME
```